# "Invalid read of size 1" error is about Copy Constructor

Tags: c++, valgrind, copy-constructor

```
Character::Character(const Character& rhs)
{
    _healthPoints = rhs._healthPoints;
    _attackPoints = rhs._attackPoints;
    _defensePoints = rhs._defensePoints;
    int i = 0;
    while(rhs._name[i] != 0)
        i++;
    int len = i;
    _name = new char[i];
    i = 0;
    for(int k = 0; k <len ; k++)
        _name[k] = rhs._name[k];
}
```

When I analyze my code by valgrind, it gave this error "Invalid read of size 1". The reason of that error is the inside of while. I neither do understand the why it cause this error or how can I fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your code explicitly zero-terminate rhs._name , or is it just lucky?

Comment: 'while(rhs._name[i] != 0)'. What if rhs._name is not pointing to anything ?

Comment: Fyi, std::string is already invented. If that's to avant garde, consider strlen. Anyway, always think about boundary conditions. What if the source string is empty? What value `len` ends up with?